# LINQ to SQL, how can I get a count of the search terms found in a field(s)?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to write a query in LINQ to return the count of the search terms found in a field(s)

Basically, I want this to work:

```
var matches = from t in _db.Books
                          let score = GetScore(t, searchterms)
                          where score >= 1
                          orderby score descending
                          select t;

public static int GetScore(Book b, params string[] searchterms)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string term in searchterms)
        {
            if (b.Title.Contains(term))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

But, of course, that can't work.
Can my little GetScore function be translated into LINQ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**:  I would also prefer to have the score accessible.  Ideally I will be selecting my results into a SearchResults class (for the View) that would contain some Book info and the Book's score from the query.   To update my query, it'd be something like this:

```
var matches = from t in _db.Books
                          let score = GetScore(t, searchterms)
                          where score >= 1
                          orderby score descending
                          select new SearchResult
                                                {
                                                    Title = t.Title,
                                                    Type = "Book",
                                                    Link = "Books/Details/" + t.BookID,
                                                    Score = score
                                                };
```

I'm sorry I wasn't more clear originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do without issuing multiple queries to the database - essentially one per search term. If you are happy to do that, then here is an easy way to do it:

```
var terms = new [] { "s", "t", "r", "e", "b", "c", };

var ids =
    from term in terms
    from id in _db.Books
        .Where(book => book.Title.Contains(term))
        .Select(book => book.Id)
    group term by id into gts
    orderby gts.Count() descending
    select gts.Key;

var selectedIds = ids.Take(50).ToArray();

var query =
    from book in _db.Books
    where selectedIds.Contains(book.Id)
    select book;
```

I wrote the `ids` to return a list of ids sorted by those that match the most terms first. This was to most closely get the same kind of result that you wanted in your question. I then decided to use a `Take(50)` to get the top 50 results. You can obviously change this strategy to suit your needs, but you must end up with an array of ids to use in the final query.

I hope this helps.

---

**EDIT: based on OP's edit.**

Here's how to query with the score included:

```
var terms = new [] { "s", "t", "r", "e", "b", "c", "l", "i", };

var idScores =
    from term in terms
    from id in _db.Books
        .Where(book => book.Title.Contains(term))
        .Select(book => book.BookID)
    group term by id into gts
    select new
    {
        Id = gts.Key,
        Score = gts.Count(),
    };

var selectedIds = idScores.Select(x => x.Id).Take(50).ToArray();

var selectedBooks =
    from book in _db.Books
    where selectedIds.Contains(book.BookID)
    select book;

var query =
    from b in selectedBooks.ToArray()
    join x in idScores on b.BookID equals x.Id
    orderby x.Score descending
    select new
    {
        Title = b.Title,
        Type = "Book",
        Link = "Books/Details/" + b.BookID,
        Score = x.Score,
    };
```

Comment: Any thoughts on my EDIT in the OP?  Sorry for the question alteration.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Disregarding my EDIT, when I try it, the first part seems to work, but when the "query" part executes, the order of the selectedIds is lost.  It just orders the results by book.Title.

Comment: @johnnycakes - I've edited my question per your edit. My original query did ignore the order of the selected ids. It still returned only the books with highest score. The new edit now properly orders the results.

Comment: This is perfect; exactly what I asked for.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your GetScore() function in LINQ then your can change whole LINQ to this:

```
               var matches = from t in _db.Books
                      where searchterms.Count(c => c == t.Title) >= 1
                      orderby searchterms.Count(c => c == t.Title)
                      select t;
```

Now it will compile successfully but on run time when you will bind this matches to grid or any where it will throw exception "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

Because "**problem is that we are trying to join an SQL table and an in-
memory list. Since you write the query against the SQL table, it goes
through LINQ to SQL, which rightly complains that it cannot do that.
so If you really want to do an in-memory join, then you must use _db.Books.AsEnumerable()**

then query will be:

```
      var matches = from t in _db.Books.AsEnumerable()
                      where searchterms.Count(c => c == t.Title) >= 1
                      orderby searchterms.Count(c => c == t.Title)
                      select t;
```

Comment: The variable `searchterms` is an array of strings and since strings do not have a `Title` property your query won't even compile.

Comment: @ Enigmativity- oh sorry i was testing it on my side but in your case it is _db.Book. I have updated answer.

Comment: I get "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." when I try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Do the search in the DB via a Stored procedure that returns a pair (BookId, Score), and then use that to do the query in LINQ2SQL
- Use ToList() to execute the query, and avoid getting the "Local sequence cannot be used..." error.

For the second option, the query (in lambda syntax) would be something like

```
db.Books
    .ToList()
    .Select(t=> new SearchResult {
                                     Title = t.Title,
                                     Type = "Book",
                                     Link = "Books/Details/" + t.BookID,
                                     Score = GetScore(t, searchTerms)
            })
    .Where(t => t.Score >=1);
```

In the latter case, you'll be bringing the whole Book table to memory (and using LINQ2Objects to do the filtering), so I'd rather go for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get filtered data tou may build Expression by your self. I make some examle for your task, but you need to improve it for your source, or create some global improvements

let's start from the end. I can't make Expression returned anonymous Type so I create Generic wich I am planning to use as result

```
public class GRes<T>
{
    public T Key { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I'm going to make grouping by any field of object or the object itself, and then on this grouping results call Sum fnction with some lambda which look's like this

```
x=>0 + IIF(x.Code.Contains(p1), 1, 0) + IIF(x.Code.Contains(p2), 1, 0) ...
```

where Code - is some field and p1,p2... - your search terms
at last call would be

```
IQueriable<GRes<Book>> result = context.Books
.GroupBy(d => d).CountIn(searchTerms, "Code")
.Where(r => r.Count > 0)
.OrderByDescending(r => r.Count);
```

CountIn - is extention :

```
public static IQueryable<GRes<TKey>> CountIn<TKey, TValue>(this IQueryable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>> source, IEnumerable<string> values, Expression<Func<TValue,string>> selector)
    {
        ParameterExpression xExpr = selector.Parameters[0];
        Expression propExpr = selector.Body;
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        Expression res = Expression.Constant(0);            
        foreach (string term in values)
        {
            Expression value = Expression.Constant(term);
            MethodCallExpression methodEpr = Expression.Call(propExpr, mi,value);
            Expression tx = Expression.Condition(methodEpr, Expression.Constant(1), Expression.Constant(0));
            res = Expression.Add(res, tx);
        }
        var r0 = Expression.Lambda<Func<pp_Disease, int>>(res, xExpr);

        Type groupingType = typeof(IGrouping<TKey, TValue>);
        ParameterExpression selPar = Expression.Parameter(groupingType, "i");
        MethodInfo mi1 = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Sum" 
                && m.ReturnParameter.ParameterType == typeof(int)
                && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(pp_Disease));

        Expression r1 = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(GRes<TKey>))
            , Expression.Bind(typeof(GRes<TKey>).GetMember("Count")[0], Expression.Call(mi1, selPar, r0))
            , Expression.Bind(typeof(GRes<TKey>).GetMember("Key")[0], Expression.Property(selPar, "Key")));
        return source.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>, GRes<TKey>>>(r1, selPar));
    }
```

and when this function would be called your get SQL like this:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM ( SELECT 
    ...
    FROM ( SELECT 
        .... 
        SUM([Extent1].[A1]) AS [A1]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            ...
            0 + (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Code] LIKE N'%2%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Code] LIKE N'%I%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [A1]
            FROM (SELECT 
      ...
      FROM [dbo].[pp_Disease] AS [pp_Disease]) AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Extent1]
        GROUP BY [K1], [K2], [K3], [K4]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
    WHERE [GroupBy1].[A1] > 0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] DESC
```

i removed some fields declarations (EF generated sql huge), most important for this example is case string with parameters that we put in our function

Answer (score -1):

```
        i took your problem as below

        books.Add("Robin HOOD");
        books.Add("Charles");
        books.Add("James");

        search.Add("Rob");
        search.Add("ood");
        search.Add("les");
        search.Add("am");

      so you want the count of search items which are found in any of the books so if run this example , you will get the  correct result.

      var temp = searchterms.Where(x=>books.Where(y=>y.Title.Contains(x)).Count()>0);
```

Comment: Your query returns a list of search terms where there exists at least one book with where the title contains the term. This isn't what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @Enigmativity : See my updated post, may be it will explain why i use above satement

Comment: The OP doesn't want a count of the search terms found in any of the books. He wants to list the books that had the most search terms found in each title in descending order. It's a very different thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
var matches = from t in _db.Books
                          let score = searchterms.Where(term => t.Title.Contains(term)).Count()
                          where score >= 1
                          orderby score descending
                          select t;
```

edit

if its linq to sql i think my solution is devide into 2 part

```
// just results in db
    string terms = searchterms.Aggregate((cur,nex) => cur+"^"+nex);
    var results = from t in _db.Books
                  where terms.Contains(t.Title.Contains)
                  select t;

// sort results in c#
    var sorting = for entry in results
                  let score = searchterms.Where(term => entry.Title.Contains(term)).Count()
                  orderby score
                  select new {......};
```

edit

oooh sorry little mistake. on first query

```
string terms = searchterms.Aggregate((cur,nex) => cur+"^"+nex);
    var results = from t in _db.Books
                  where terms.Contains(t.Title.Contains)
                  select t;
```

change to

```
string terms = searchterms.Aggregate((cur,nex) => cur+"^"+nex);
    var results = from t in _db.Books
                  where terms.Contains("^" + t.Title + "^")
                  select t;
```

the reason i use this query is 'var results' will gives all the result from db which should be ok becus it's string.Contains. Then sort the result in next query.

Comment: Your query doesn't work in linq-to-sql. "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: Now your query doesn't compile. Are you using a tool like LINQPad to test out your queries?